# What does var msg="" stand for in javascript?

Tags: javascript, initialization

What does `var msg=""` mean in javascript? I don't understand the `""` bit.

Comment: it's probably to setup msg for using msg+=" more text" down the road...

Answer (score 7):

It declares a variable called `msg` using

```
var msg
```

and assigns it a value:

```
= "";
```

The `""` is just an empty string, that is, basically an empty text. Please note that this is different from no text at all (which you had if you did not assign anything, or used `undefined` or `null` instead of `""`).

It basically is the same difference as the difference between an empty set and no set in math. `""` means that the type of the variable basically is text, just no value is given. `undefined` means that the type is not known, and hence no value is available.

Finally, please note that you can also put this code into two separate lines:

```
var msg; // declaration
msg = ""; // definition
```

Instead having

```
var msg = "";
```

is just a convenience feature. Generally speaking, as you said that you're new to JavaScript, you should lookup the concept of *variable hoisting*, because JavaScript internally splits your line in a separate declaration and definition part.

Answer (score 5):

It declares a variable named `msg`, and initializes it with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

By parts:

- [`var` declares a new variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) scoped to the nearest containing function (or the global scope, if there is none (in which case the `var` keyword is optional and implicit))
- `msg` is the name of this new variable (i.e. its *identifier*)
- `=` is the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), which assigns the value on its right-hand side to whatever is on its left-hand side
- `""` is a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) representing the string having zero characters (i.e. the empty string)

Answer (score 1):

The `""` basically means "initialize a new string with no characters". Double quotes around letters denotes a `string` variable type, e.g.:

```
var name = "Dave";
```

So the statement

```
var msg = ""
```

Says create a variable named `msg`, and set it to a string with no characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I've read the count of ' correctly, it is an empty string. It initializes the variable and declares and allocates it with the value of an empty String.